# JQ плавное появление HTML

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который добавляет текст в DIV элемент:

```
$(myDiv).html(myText);
```

Текст в элементе появляется моментально, как сделать что бы он появлялся плавно?

Comment: что за VID элемент

Comment: ошибся, DIV элемент то есть

Comment: вы хотите используя именно метод html сделать эффект плавности?

Comment: да, именно метод html

Answer (score 2):

источник https://stackoverflow.com/q/11679567

```js
var qwa = qwa || document.getElementById('qwa')
let addToQwa = (text = 'some text') => qwa.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<span>${text}</span>`)
setTimeout(() => {
  addToQwa()
  setTimeout(() => {
    addToQwa('some new text')
  }, 1e3);
}, 1e3);
```

```css
#qwa span {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  /* font-size: 21px; */
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="qwa">qwa</div>
```

Comment: вопрос а первая строка кода что делает можете обяснить ?какой смысл ?присваиваеть переменной значение либо ID либо саму себя я никак не понимаю..

Comment: `div id="qwa"` создаёт глобальную переменную с именем `qwa` но не всегда, поэтому `|| document.getElementById('qwa')` ; `var qwa = qwa` в глобальном пространстве имён не перезаписывает `qwa`

Comment: спасибо плюсь к ответу

Answer (score 0):

Сделай элемент myDiv `display:none`

И после `$(myDiv).html(myText);`

Добавь `$(myDiv).fadeIn('500');`